# Produce the LaTeX logo in MS Word

Tags: msword

How can I produce the result of `\LaTeX` (and also `\TeX` and `\XeLaTeX`) in MS Word?

**EDIT**: Since I don't see an actual reason for closing this question (there are already lots of questions/answers on TEX.SX that do not directly consider TeX/LaTeX methods), I voted to reopen it.

Comment: Sorry, but this is off-topic. I guess one can do that, but not with TeX and LaTeX methods. `;-)`

Comment: Maybe this answer might help: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/comp.text/MdYAkrbIskA/6qeO6VGkzsUJ

Comment: I flagged this question for migration to [su]. (Btw, the downvote is an automated result of the question's being closed as off-topic. Nobody actually downvoted it.)

Comment: Produce it in LaTeX, make it into an image, insert the image.

Comment: @Canageek that is what I'll probably do, thanks. I was just hoping for a more "automatic" solution.

Comment: @neils You can also use character insert to make it.

Comment: @Canageek actually it looks good enough using picture insertion, but I'll also consider this solution when I get back to my document next time. Thanks!

Comment: The answer to this question would help me, even some guys may think this is off-topic!